# Starting the Maps app with coordinates as argument

Tags: android, android-activity, maps

I'm wondering if i could start the maps app in "get directions" mode with coordinates x and y as destination point and the current position as start point.

Any ideas how could i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah there is an undocumented, unofficial way to do it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + source.getLatitude() + "," + source.getLongitude() + "&daddr=" + getLatitude() + "," + dest.getLongitude()));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Applies to integration with any app: decompile the app with [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), look at the AndroidManifest.xml and .smali code to figure out what intent with what parameters you need to call to get desired effect.

The big downside of this approach is, since you're using undocumented "entry point", when new version of e.g. Maps comes along, your app is likely to break.